# Noninteractively upgrade all packages

Tags: package

I want my emacs to automatically upgrade all packages under certain conditions.

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Here is a command fo upgrade all outdated packages: https://github.com/Malabarba/paradox/blob/2.3.5/paradox.el#L165-L181 (replace all `paradox` with `package`).

Comment: @xuchunyang Ah. I see that doesn't look too bad. If you make that an answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want (I don't know what you mean by “under
certain conditions”), but here is a function I use to upgrade all packages
without showing `*Packages*` buffer, which I find annoying when I just want to
upgrade packages.

```el
(defun package-upgrade-all ()
  "Upgrade all packages automatically without showing *Packages* buffer."
  (interactive)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (let (upgrades)
    (cl-flet ((get-version (name where)
                (let ((pkg (cadr (assq name where))))
                  (when pkg
                    (package-desc-version pkg)))))
      (dolist (package (mapcar #'car package-alist))
        (let ((in-archive (get-version package package-archive-contents)))
          (when (and in-archive
                     (version-list-< (get-version package package-alist)
                                     in-archive))
            (push (cadr (assq package package-archive-contents))
                  upgrades)))))
    (if upgrades
        (when (yes-or-no-p
               (message "Upgrade %d package%s (%s)? "
                        (length upgrades)
                        (if (= (length upgrades) 1) "" "s")
                        (mapconcat #'package-desc-full-name upgrades ", ")))
          (save-window-excursion
            (dolist (package-desc upgrades)
              (let ((old-package (cadr (assq (package-desc-name package-desc)
                                             package-alist))))
                (package-install package-desc)
                (package-delete  old-package)))))
      (message "All packages are up to date"))))
```

This is well-tried. It also prevents compilation buffers from popping up.

Comment: Nice. I'm going to use this with a slight variation that doesn't prompt before upgrading the packages.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you do `(y-or-n-p (message ..))` instead of just `(y-or-n-p ...)`?

Comment: @PythonNut, Well I need to construct prompt message, I don't remember now why I use `message`, it seems it can be done with `format` just as well.

Comment: Ah yes. I meant using `format`. Obviously you can't do it without any sort of string interpolation.

Comment: Emacs's `package.el` now ships with a command `package-upgrade-all`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [auto-package-update](https://github.com/rranelli/auto-package-update.el).

Install it by `M-x package-install auto-update-package`. It provides a function called `auto-package-update-now`. You can write a simple `if` condition and add that to your `.emacs`.

```
(if your-condition
   (auto-package-update-now))
```

Comment: Hm... I'll keep this in mind, but the idea is to try automatically fixing packaged if they are broken. Depending on a package to do so is kinda nonsensical. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The package is now called auto-package update. (Too low reputation to write it as a comment to the Chillar post above).

(Copied from his post and merged with this answer):

Install it by `M-x package-install auto-package-update`. It provides a function called `auto-package-update-now`. You can write a simple if condition and add that to your `~/.emacs`.

```
(if your-condition
   (auto-package-update-now))
```

Comment: I've edited Chillar's answer to correct the package name, we can delete this one now I think.