# Upgrading packages automatically

Tags: package

I'm trying to write a command that upgrades all packages, no questions asked. It looks like:

```
(defun *-package-upgrade ()
  "Upgrade all packages"
  (interactive)
  (save-window-excursion
    (package-list-packages)
    (with-current-buffer "*Packages*"
      (package-menu-mark-upgrades)
      (package-menu-mark-obsolete-for-deletion)
      (package-menu-execute t))))
```

However, when it's run, I see:

```
Importing package-keyring.gpg...done
Waiting for refresh to finish...
user-error: No operations specified
Package refresh done
25 packages marked for upgrading.
```

Which seems to suggest that `package-menu-mark-upgrades` is running *after* `package-menu-execute`.

I thought `package-menu-mark-upgrades` may be running asynchronously, but the docstring of the `package-menu-async` customizable variable says:

> Currently, only the refreshing of archive contents supports asynchronous operations.  Package transactions are still done synchronously.

So I'm not sure what's going on here.

P.S. I've taken a look at a [related question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16398/noninteractively-upgrade-all-packages), but I'd prefer to write my own command for this.

Comment: Given your question boils down to "what is wrong with my code" rather than "how do I script package upgrades" (as in the linked question), I suggest you reword the title of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Importing package-keyring.gpg...done
Waiting for refresh to finish...
user-error: No operations specified
Package refresh done
25 packages marked for upgrading.
```

> Which seems to suggest that `package-menu-mark-upgrades` is running after `package-menu-execute`.

Not necessarily. This only suggests that when `package-menu-execute` is run, there are no operations to perform; in other words, that no packages have been marked by `pakage-menu-mark-upgrades` or `package-menu-mark-obsolete-for-deletion`.

This, in turn, is probably because `package-menu-async` defaults to non-`nil`, which causes `package-list-packages` to run asynchronously, which means the function returns before `package.el` has fetched the latest package data and determined which packages are upgrade/obsoletion candidates. This is confirmed by the message `"Waiting for refresh to finish..."`, which is emitted by `package-menu-mark-upgrades` when a download is still in progress.

Setting/binding `package-menu-async` to `nil` before calling `package-list-packages` should result in the upgrades and deletions happening as expected, but the retrieval and subsequent actions will be synchronous and thus obstruct you from otherwise interacting with Emacs for their duration.

Either way, you should wrap the call to `package-menu-execute` in something like `condition-case` to handle the error it emits when there are no packages to be upgraded or deleted. Note also that `save-window-excursion`, as its docstring describes, is an unreliable protection against buffer/window/frame configuration changes. Even if it were reliable, `package-menu-execute` would and will still pop up the `*Packages*` buffer for the duration of any synchronous package upgrades. Hence the complexity of the [answer you link to](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16407/15748).

Here is how you could modify your function to work synchronously, as described above:

```el
(defun my-package-upgrade ()
  "Refresh, upgrade and delete obsolete packages synchronously."
  (interactive)
  (save-window-excursion
    (let (package-menu-async)
      (package-list-packages)))
  (with-current-buffer "*Packages*"
    (package-menu-mark-upgrades)
    (package-menu-mark-obsolete-for-deletion)
    (condition-case err
        (package-menu-execute t)
      ;; Don't barf if there is nothing to do
      (user-error (message "Nothing to do"))
      ;; But allow other errors through
      (error (signal (car err) (cdr err))))))
```

Here is a bad example of how you could write your function to keep package refreshes asynchronous whilst performing any marking/upgrades at the right time. As such, this is a compromise between setting `package-menu-async` to `nil` and using the code from the linked answer.

```el
(defun my-package-upgrade ()
  "Refresh, upgrade and delete obsolete packages."
  (interactive)
  (letrec ((hook
            (lambda ()
              (unwind-protect
                  (with-current-buffer "*Packages*"
                    (package-menu-mark-upgrades)
                    (package-menu-mark-obsolete-for-deletion)
                    (condition-case err
                        (package-menu-execute t)
                      (user-error (message "Nothing to do"))
                      (error (signal (car err) (cdr err)))))
                (remove-hook 'package--post-download-archives-hook hook)))))
    (save-window-excursion
      (package-list-packages)
      (add-hook 'package--post-download-archives-hook hook t))))
```

What makes this a kludge is:

1. The (unlikely) race condition between the calls to `package-list-packages` and `add-hook` in an attempt to run `hook` after the other functions on this hook variable.
2. The fact that `package.el` isn't designed to be used/scripted like this. Even replacing hooks with well-placed function advice would be a bit of a kludge.

YMMV, of course.

Comment: Hmm. I'm surprised that this relatively simple task (upgrade package automatically) has such a difficult solution. I'll leave the question open in case anyone has a better way.

Comment: @TianxiangXiong Automatic package upgrade is already covered by https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/16398/15748. The simplest fix for your original function, as I've explained, is setting `package-menu-async` to `nil` around the call to `package-list-packages`. `package.el` simply doesn't support fully asynchronous operations yet.

Comment: @TianxiangXiong If you are asking about how to make package upgrades fully automatic, e.g. by checking for new packages every few hours or so, then your question does not make this clear.

Comment: Thanks--I glossed over the synchronous part too quickly. It works fine for my needs.