# package-autoremove doesn't work

Tags: package, upgrade

I tried to use

```
M-x package-autoremove
```

but my `.emacs.d` directory is still a mess: it's full with several versions of the same package. As side info I use the `no-littering` package, but when I update packages the old versions are kept in the `elpa` directory.

I also tried to manually delete old packages. For example if I run

```
M-x package-list
```

I get the package list, and at some point in the list I have

```
no-littering    20190409.1154 installed   help keeping ~/.emacs.d clean
```

at the end of the list I have

```
no-littering       1.0.0         obsolete    help keeping ~/.emacs.d clean
no-littering       20190129.2355 obsolete    help keeping ~/.emacs.d clean
```

and these 3 versions have 3 corresponding folders in the ELPA directory. Therefore I presume that the last 2 entries are old versions, and I mark both of them for deletion (d) and than I  execute the deletion with (x). The mini-buffer tells me to run

```
M-x package-autoremove
```

which I do, and in fact the corresponding 2 folders in ELPA directory disappeared. But after that when I reload emacs I get an initialization error do to no-littering.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`package-autoremove` removes packages returned by `package--removable-packages`:

> Return a list of names of packages no longer needed.
>   These are packages which are neither contained in
>   `package-selected-packages` nor a dependency of one that is.

Old versions is marked for deletion by invoking `package-menu-mark-upgrades`:

> Mark all upgradable packages in the Package Menu.
>   For each installed package with a newer version available, place
>   an (I)nstall flag on the available version and a (D)elete flag on
>   the installed version.

How do you upgrade installed packages?

Comment: I use ```M-x auto-package-update-now```

Comment: Is the `auto-package-update-delete-old-versions` set to `t`? Though I don't use auto-package-update.

Comment: no I don't have this package, I'll try it, any particular suggestion to use it?

Comment: I don't get it. Where is `auto-package-update-now` function defined then?

Comment: I just added  ```(require 'auto-package-update)
(setq auto-package-update-delete-old-versions t)```  to my ```init.el```  file. I reloaded emacs and ran ```M-x auto-package-update-now``` . It updated new versions, old versions are still there.

Comment: Looking around I have seen a lot of issues similar to this. Is it safe to "manually" delete old versions folder in the ELPA directory? I know this is a bit crude

Comment: Better use `M-x package-delete`. It will check dependencies and remove `NAME-VERSION.signed` and `NAME-readme.txt` files if any.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is the best solution I could find.

First I reproduced a fresh install:

1. I went in `~/.emacs.d/elpa` and a noted the list of folders. There were packages with 7 or 8 different version number, it was a mess! With this I got the full list of installed packages
2. I simply deleted the content of `~/.emacs.d/elpa`
3. I restarted emacs and installed all needed packages with `M-x package-list-packages` (mark the package to be installed with `i` install pressing `x`
4. Now with fresh install on my machine I added this into the `init.el`:

```lisp
(defun package-upgrade-all ()
  "Upgrade all packages automatically without showing *Packages* buffer."
  (interactive)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (let (upgrades)
    (cl-flet ((get-version (name where)
                (let ((pkg (cadr (assq name where))))
                  (when pkg
                    (package-desc-version pkg)))))
      (dolist (package (mapcar #'car package-alist))
        (let ((in-archive (get-version package package-archive-contents)))
          (when (and in-archive
                     (version-list-< (get-version package package-alist)
                                     in-archive))
            (push (cadr (assq package package-archive-contents))
                  upgrades)))))
    (if upgrades
        (when (yes-or-no-p
               (message "Upgrade %d package%s (%s)? "
                        (length upgrades)
                        (if (= (length upgrades) 1) "" "s")
                        (mapconcat #'package-desc-full-name upgrades ", ")))
          (save-window-excursion
            (dolist (package-desc upgrades)
              (let ((old-package (cadr (assq (package-desc-name package-desc)
                                             package-alist))))
                (package-install package-desc)
                (package-delete  old-package)))))
      (message "All packages are up to date"))))
```

The latter was suggested [form here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16407/23546). This is brilliant! Now the following

```lisp
M-x  package-upgrade-all
```

magically upgrades all packages and remove the previous installed version with all its auxiliary files. Great!

I tested the function extensively and it works beautifully.

I consider this question solved.